# Search cell for two separate strings using InStr

Tags: vba, excel

I have a conditional that will enter "PRO1 10.5" into cell H1 if "iPad Pro 10.5" can be found in cell A1. But, the formatting varies and "iPad Pro" and "10.5" may be separated in A1 -- For example:

> "Apple iPad Pro 2nd Gen. 64GB, Wi-Fi, 10.5in Space Gray"

For cases such as this, how should I search for these two divided strings to end with my desired result? There are several other sizes and models that require specific classification, too.

Here is my current code

```
For Each cell In SrchRng
    If InStr(1, cell.Value, "iPad Pro 10.5", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        cell.Offset(0, 7).Value = "PRO1 10.5"
    End If
Next cell
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Like` operator to see if a String matches a pattern.

```
If cell.Value Like "*iPad Pro*10.5*" Then
```

This will be a match if the cell contains any string where both "iPad Pro" and "10.5" are substrings, in that order.

Comment: I `Like` this solution, because it respects string order. To make it work case-insensitive: `If LCase(cell.Value) Like "*ipad pro*10.5*" Then`

Answer (score 0):

Just change the condition :

```
If InStr(1, cell.Value, "iPad Pro 10.5", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
```

to

```
If InStr(1, cell.Value, "iPad Pro", vbTextCompare) > 0  and If InStr(1, cell.Value, "10.5", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
```